# Python : Convert multiple images as multiple pages in pdf for windows

Tags: python, pdf-generation

How to convert multiple images(jpeg) as a pdf file with multiple pages in windows.

Using Image library, i can convert every image as single pdf, i can merge those converted files to a single pdf file using pdfminer, but it is two way work.

I try to download MagicK, but couldn't get binary for windows.  Is it possible to achieve using PIL ?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Comment: Downvoted for not looking carefully

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but you can create a report with jasperReport and create a pdf file after. I believe python also can work with jasper reports. 
what do you think? maybe is too much work.